# Python context manager to decorator (and inversely)

Tags: python, decorator, yield, contextmanager

I would like to have:

```
# Simple example, one could replace try/except by any other nested construct
def mycontextmanager_generator(foo):
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print 'bar'
        raise

mycontextmanager = build_contextmanager(mycontextmanager_generator)
mydecorator = build_decorator(mycontextmanager_generator)


>>> with mycontextmanager():
>>>     raise Exception('baz gone bar in context manager')
... bar


>>> @mydecorator()
>>> def bazzer():
>>>     raise Exception('baz gone bar in decorator')
>>> bazzer()
... bar
```

In this example, I build a context manager from a generator function, and a decorator from the same function. This is what I tried to achieve in an unsuccessful way.

More generally, what I want is to be DRY: **write once the `try/except` block, and re-use it through both a decorator *and* a context manager** Again: by writing the try/except bloc *only once*, whether in a generator function or any other wrapper.

The `ContextDecorator` thing (in `contextlib` in py3 / `contextlib2` in py2) is only usable with classes, but it seems to be useless in that case... Am I missing something? Is there a means to implement my try/except block with a class-based ContextManager using `__enter__` and `__exit__`?

Or is there a possibility to transform a contextmanager built with `yield` syntax into a decorator?

Or the contrary (decorator to contextmanager)?

If no, would be happy to know what is the limitation of Python for that matter.

To my understanding, the `yield` syntax is very tightly bound to the Python interpreter and context switching, and I don't know if it is possible to change its behavior on that point.

Comment: So you want to use `yield` but still except the exception the case above, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You appear to be referencing an external library, I think I know which one you mean, but I'm second guessing here ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/contextdecorator ). Please could you state which libraries you are using, which version of Python and a more concrete example of the behaviour you want (sample/pseudo code, plus expected/desired output).

Comment: @Dunes in py3 it's in `contextlib` (which I guessed anyone playing with decorators and context managers will know), but indeed I'm going to update the question for more clarity

Comment: Don't be condescending. There is very little reason to know about `ContextDecorator` unless you have to work with python versions that do not support the `with` statement. I use `contextlib` frequently, and have simply never had need for the `ContextDecorator` class.

Comment: @Dunes hey no offense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler to understand solution than Dunes' one, albeit not taking advantage of `ContextDecorator` double-syntax.

```
import contextlib
import functools

def handler():
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print 'bar'


my_contextmanager = contextlib.contextmanager(handler)


def my_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with my_contextmanager():
            func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


with my_contextmanager():
    raise Exception('baz')

@my_decorator
def f():
    raise Exception('baz')

f()
```

gives:

```
bar
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve what you need by combining the class that `contextmanager` uses to manage its contexts (`_GeneratorContextManager`) and the `ContextDecorator` class. eg.

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator, _GeneratorContextManager
from functools import wraps

class MyContextManager(_GeneratorContextManager, ContextDecorator):
    pass

def contextmanager(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def helper(*args, **kwds):
        return MyContextManager(func, args, kwds)
    return helper

@contextmanager
def print_bar_on_error():
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print('bar')
        raise

with print_bar_on_error():
    raise Exception('baz gone bar in context manager')
```

produces:

```
bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise Exception('baz gone bar in context manager')
Exception: baz gone bar in context manager
```

And when used as a decorator

```
@print_bar_on_error()
def bazzer():
    raise Exception('baz gone bar in decorator')
bazzer()
```

produces:

```
bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 32, in <module>
    bazzer()
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "run.py", line 31, in bazzer
    raise Exception('baz gone bar in decorator')
Exception: baz gone bar in decorator
    return func(*args, **kwds)
Exception: baz gone bar in decorator
```

Comment: Indeed that works, I didn't take the right look at `ContextDecorator`. Now that I understand what contextlib does, it doesn't seem so simple to me, I'm posting an alternative solution (less nifty to use, but simpler to understand)